# How to remove all enqueued assets from the active theme?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

https://gelwp.com/articles/removing-all-enqueued-and-default-css-scripts-in-wordpress/ has code that removes all the enqueued styles including those that may be coming from other plugins besides the ones from the active theme.

Is it possible to remove all enqueued assets from only the current active theme without hardcoding the theme name or when it is not known which theme is active?

i.e., achieve the result of

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentynineteen_scripts' );
```

when twentynineteen theme is active

or

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwenty_register_styles' );
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwenty_register_scripts' );
```

when twentytwenty is active.

Comment: WordPress doesn’t know whether scripts or styles were enqueue by a theme or plugin. You can’t even rely on the URL, because themes could enqueue external assets. What’s your ultimate goal here? If it’s a child theme, the just check the parent theme manually to find all the asset handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. I took this out of my mailoptin plugin. Adapt the code to your use case.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () use ($wp_get_theme) {
                global $wp_styles;
                global $wp_scripts;

            $wp_get_theme = wp_get_theme();

                $child_theme  = $wp_get_theme->get_stylesheet();
                $parent_theme = $wp_get_theme->get_template();

                foreach ($wp_scripts->registered as $key => $value) {
                    $src = $value->src;
                    if (strpos($src, "themes/$child_theme/") !== false || strpos($src, "themes/$parent_theme/") !== false) {
                        unset($wp_scripts->registered[$key]);
                    }

                    if (strpos($src, "/uploads/$child_theme/") !== false || strpos($src, "/uploads/$parent_theme/") !== false) {
                        unset($wp_scripts->registered[$key]);
                    }


                }

            }, 20);
```

Comment: Thanks Collins.

This following works: https://pastebin.com/raw/zS4zyYxs.